# Select the 5 latest records in a table with PHP and fill an ordered list with that in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to learn how to fill an ordered list in a html page with the 5 records in a table with the latest timestamp using php. Most components I have figured out (struggling a bit with php) but that will be fine eventually. The challenge for me is mostly to let it talk to each other in a right way. As soon as someone visits my webpage the top 5 list should be filled. So the php should go off at the moment someone visits my page. Does that mean I just place it on top of the index page? I prefer to have it seperate in another php file and store the rows as session variables en take them back in at the index page.

The html list:

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...")
                or die ("kan niet connecten met database");

$top_5_overview = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM search_table ORDER BY upgedate DESC LIMIT 5")
                    or die ("kan query1 niet uitvoeren");

$top_5 = mysqli_fetch_array($top_5_overview);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<ol>
<?php
foreach ($top_5 as $t){
    echo '<li> <a href="'.$t['url'].'" target='_blank'>'.$t['atlasnaam'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify more baout what you want to do and what have you tried till now?

Comment: So far I am just trying to fill the list with the results of my php code. The next step would be to integrate this in the start of my index page of my website. I just updated the code based on a now deleted answer that was here. Think I am close! But this does not show anything when I run it on my server. Error code 500.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work? Are there any errors in the console or mysql? I am confused, it should work well.

Comment: well I saved it as a file. top_5_test.php and placed this on the server and then went to the domain www.domain.nl/top_5_test.php and it gives the error code 500. Now I dont know where to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in the code sample that you sent.

1. The `SQL` should have `DESC` after the column name, not before it.
2. The call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns **only** one row of the results. You can use a `while` loop to iterate through the 5 rows that you are expecting. The `while` loop also protects against empty results, if no rows are returned, the code inside the loop never gets called.
3. Your `foreach` won't work as expected since you are passing **one** row as the array, it tries to iterate through the values on the array.
4. There is a problem in the way you mix single and double quotes, `'` and `"`, in your string, in concrete `"target='_blank'>` it makes `_blank` not part of the string, and so part of the "code".

This code example works for me:

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("...", "...", "...", "...")
    or die ("kan niet connecten met database");

$result = mysqli_query($connection, 
    "SELECT * FROM search_table ORDER BY upgedate DESC LIMIT 5")
    or die ("kan query1 niet uitvoeren");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . 
                $row['url'] . '" target="_blank">' . 
                $row['atlasnaam'] . '</a></li>';
        } ?>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

top_5_overview lacks $ in the beginning, it should be $top_5_overview.

And you don't bind the result of that query to your $top_5 -array. Instead in your code there is mysqli_fetch_array($query1)

Try this:

```
$top_5_overview = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM search_table 
ORDER BY upgedate DESC LIMIT 5")
                or die ("kan query1 niet uitvoeren");
$top_5 = mysqli_fetch_array($top_5_overview);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. That was a stupid mistake and fixed that. Still getting the same Error code 500.

Comment: Updated the SQL query, DESC should be after the column name

Comment: Just saw that and fixed it. I think the mistake is in this part: 

<?php
foreach ($top_5 as $t){
    echo '<li> <a href="'.$t['url'].'" target='_blank'>'.$t['atlasnaam'].'</a></li>';
}
?> Just got a list on the page but it has weird entries coming from 'url' and 'atlasnaam'. Also the list goes to 15 while I clearly only take 5 records in the SQL statement.